# JS Promise: control flow

Tags: javascript, promise, chaining

I have to set a few things up via an API. It's important that the different functions are executed after each other. All of the listed functions return a proper promise.

```
a(analyticsConfig._listConfig)
    .then(function() {
        return b(listName, analyticsConfig._fieldConfig);
    })
    .then(function() {
        return c(listName)
    })
    .then(function() {
        return d(analyticsConfig._roleConfig);
    })
```

I'd like to use something like `a.then(b(listName, analyticsConfig._fieldConfig))` or so but as you probably know this won't work.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it as

```
a.then(b.bind(null, listName, analyticsConfig._fieldConfig))
```

or, if you're either using [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile your code, or you're targeting a version of node > v4., you can do

```
a.then(() => b(listName, analyticsConfig._fieldConfig))
```

Comment: Beware that the arrow functions are not supported in any IE browser.

Comment: I would `bind` to `null`, not to `this`, to more closely model the original call

Comment: Great answer thanks alot. What about error handling? Is there a way to use one single `.catch()` for the whole chain?

Answer (score 4):

That will only work if `b` returns a function that returns a promise. You always *must* pass a *function* to `then` as the callback, there's no way around that. There are however many ways to construct one.

Leaving partial application (with `bind` or other), currying and such stuff aside, your best options for nicer syntax are ES8 `async`/`await`

```
(async function() {
    await a(analyticsConfig._listConfig);
    await b(listName, analyticsConfig._fieldConfig);
    await c(listName);
    await d(analyticsConfig._roleConfig);
})();
```

or ES6 arrow functions:

```
a(analyticsConfig._listConfig)
.then(() => b(listName, analyticsConfig._fieldConfig))
.then(() => c(listName))
.then(() => d(analyticsConfig._roleConfig))
```

Comment: Probably works, although I used the other solution because I'm not allowed to use ES5+ features. (Still upvoted though!)

Answer (score 1):

You can bind it:

```
a.then(b.bind(context,listName,analyticsConfig._fieldConfig))
```

Be sure to bind the expected context to it though.

According to [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following using async/await:

```
function a() {
    console.log('Getting A...');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('Hello A!');
        }, 1000);
    });
}

function b() {
    console.log('Getting B...');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('Hello B!');
        }, 1000);
    });
}

function c() {
    console.log('Getting C...');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('Hello C!');
        }, 1000);
    });
}

function d() {
    console.log('Getting D...');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('Hello D!');
        }, 1000);
    });
}

async function getAll() {
    await a();
    await b();
    await c();
    await d();
    console.log('Done');
}
```